# Convert array of strings into a string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want the Java code for converting an array of strings into an string.

Comment: `array.toString()` ? Be more specific.

Comment: @Princeyesuraj, the _official_ answer is provided by _adarshr_. If you want own separator, you can try _JoeSlav_'s answer, and if no thread problem, you can use _StringBuilder_ instead of _StringBuffer_ for effiency. _krock_'s answer is good, but a little bit overkilling in my opinion.

Answer (score 625, accepted):

### Java 8+

Use `String.join()`:

```
String str = String.join(",", arr);
```

Note that `arr` can also be any `Iterable` (such as a list), not just an array.

If you have a `Stream`, you can use the joining collector:

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "c")
      .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

### Legacy (Java 7 and earlier)

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : arr) {
    builder.append(s);
}
String str = builder.toString();
```

Alternatively, if you just want a "debug-style" dump of an array:

```
String str = Arrays.toString(arr);
```

Note that if you're *really* legacy (Java 1.4 and earlier) you'll need to replace `StringBuilder` there with `StringBuffer`.

### Android

Use `TextUtils.join()`:

```
String str = TextUtils.join(",", arr);
```

### General notes

You can modify all the above examples depending on what characters, if any, you want in between strings.

**DON'T** use a string and just append to it with += in a loop like some of the answers show here. This sends the GC through the roof because you're creating and throwing away as many string objects as you have items in your array. For small arrays you might not really notice the difference, but for large ones it can be orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on why StringBuilder is superior to += for appending.

Comment: May I suggest the "Either use Array.toString()" part. That produces useless output such as "[Ljava.lang.String;@25154f".

Comment: If you use a += under the covers Java will convert that to using a StringBuilder.

Comment: @Javamann Not if you do the concatenation in a loop (such as here.)

Comment: @matteo, You have to use `Arrays.toString(yourArray);` but i guess You used `yourArray.toString();`

Comment: Note, that Arrays.toString will produce String like this "[cat, mouse]"

Comment: Since java ```1.8``` you can also use [```String::join```](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-), instead of the for-loop. ```String.join("", arr);```

Comment: How is the inverse process done? If I have a string that contains an array of strings, how do I convert it back to an array of strings? [EDIT] There's already an answer to my question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413586/string-to-string-array-conversion-in-java

Comment: Android developers can use like String result = TextUtils.join(", ", list);
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802971/alternative-for-string-join-in-android

Answer (score 106):

Use Apache commons [`StringUtils.join()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.String)).  It takes an array, as a parameter (and also has overloads for `Iterable` and `Iterator` parameters) and calls `toString()` on each element (if it is not null) to get each elements string representation.  Each elements string representation is then joined into one string with a separator in between if one is specified:

```
String joinedString = StringUtils.join(new Object[]{"a", "b", 1}, "-");
System.out.println(joinedString);
```

Produces:

```
a-b-1
```

Answer (score 38):

I like using [Google's Guava Joiner](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) for this, e.g.:

```
Joiner.on(", ").skipNulls().join("Harry", null, "Ron", "Hermione");
```

would produce the same String as:

```
new String("Harry, Ron, Hermione");
```

ETA: Java 8 has similar support now:

```
String.join(", ", "Harry", "Ron", "Hermione");
```

Can't see support for skipping null values, but that's easily worked around.

Comment: But if we were being true to the plot, `null` would be "he whose name must not be mentioned" :-)

Comment: If you're brave: ;-) `Joiner.on(", ").useForNull("Voldemort").join("Harry", null, "Ron", "Hermione");`

Comment: Using java-8 `String.join(", ", "Harry", null, "Ron", "Hermione").replaceAll("null", "Voldermart");`

Answer (score 18):

From Java 8, the simplest way I think is:

```
    String[] array = { "cat", "mouse" };
    String delimiter = "";
    String result = String.join(delimiter, array);
```

This way you can choose an arbitrary delimiter.

Answer (score 13):

You could do this, given an array `a` of primitive type:

```
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   result.append( a[i] );
   //result.append( optional separator );
}
String mynewstring = result.toString();
```

Comment: StringBuffer is old, use StringBuilder instead which does not have unneeded synchronization for use in one thread.

Answer (score 10):

Try the [Arrays.deepToString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method.

Returns a string representation of the "deep contents" of the specified
     array.  If the array contains other arrays as elements, the string
     representation contains their contents and so on.  This method is
     designed for converting multidimensional arrays to strings

Comment: If you don't need a lot of control, I believe this is the simplest solution since you don't need a third party lib.  Here is an example: System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(args));

Answer (score 7):

Try the [Arrays.toString](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) overloaded methods.

Or else, try this below generic implementation:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    String[] array = {"ABC", "XYZ", "PQR"};

    System.out.println(new Test().join(array, ", "));
}

public <T> String join(T[] array, String cement) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    if(array == null || array.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    for (T t : array) {
        builder.append(t).append(cement);
    }

    builder.delete(builder.length() - cement.length(), builder.length());

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Then tell us the format you are looking for. Otherwise, we can't guess what you have in mind.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ArrayToString
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] strArray = new String[]{"Java", "PHP", ".NET", "PERL", "C", "COBOL"};
        
        String newString = Arrays.toString(strArray);
        
        newString = newString.substring(1, newString.length()-1);

        System.out.println("New New String: " + newString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want code which produce string from arrayList,

```
Iterate through all elements in list and add it to your String result
```

you can do this in 2 ways: using String as result or StringBuffer/StringBuilder.

**Example:**

```
String result = "";
for (String s : list) {
    result += s;
}
```

...but this isn't good practice because of performance reason. Better is using [StringBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) (threads safe) or [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) which are more appropriate to adding Strings

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache Commons' [StringUtils library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)'s join method.

```
String[] stringArray = {"a","b","c"};
StringUtils.join(stringArray, ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] strings = new String[25000];
for (int i = 0; i < 25000; i++) strings[i] = '1234567';

String result;
result = "";
for (String s : strings) result += s;
//linear +: 5s

result = "";
for (String s : strings) result = result.concat(s);
//linear .concat: 2.5s

result = String.join("", strings);
//Java 8 .join: 3ms

Public String join(String delimiter, String[] s)
{
    int ls = s.length;
    switch (ls)
    {
        case 0: return "";
        case 1: return s[0];
        case 2: return s[0].concat(delimiter).concat(s[1]);
        default:
            int l1 = ls / 2;
            String[] s1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(s, 0, l1); 
            String[] s2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(s, l1, ls); 
            return join(delimiter, s1).concat(delimiter).concat(join(delimiter, s2));
    }
}
result = join("", strings);
// Divide&Conquer join: 7ms
```

If you don't have the choise but to use Java 6 or 7 then you should use Divide&Conquer join.

Answer (score 0):

```
String array[]={"one","two"};
String s="";

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
  s=s+array[i];
}

System.out.print(s);
```

Comment: Your answer is basically the same as smas; just a bit more complicated; thus sure not "the most easy" one. And besides, Arrays.toString() is even easier.

Answer (score 0):

When we use stream we do have more flexibility, like 
map --> convert any array object to toString
filter --> remove when it is empty
join --> Adding joining character

```
    //Deduplicate the comma character in the input string
    String[] splits = input.split("\\s*,\\s*");
    return Arrays.stream(splits).filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Answer (score -22):

If you know how much elements the array has, a simple way is doing this:

```
String appendedString = "" + array[0] + "" + array[1] + "" + array[2] + "" + array[3];
```

Comment: That's hardly applicable in real world and shows some bad programming practices.

Comment: Could be great a gold medal for achieve -50 negatives

Comment: If a person knows how many elements he has, he mostly will also know what are the elements. So, this answer makes no sense.