# parsing string to array or list

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

In Java, I have a string output like this but I have no idea about how to deal with

I mean when I `WriteLine(myString)` or `printLn(myString)`

```
   [["-1.816513","52.5487566"],["-1.8164913","52.548824"]]
```

after parsing it should be a list of string's list like below

```
List<List<Sring>> myList
```

`list.get(0).get(0);` should give me "-1.816513"

Any idea about how to parse this string to this list?

Comment: what programming language are you using?  Also, SO questions generally need to demonstrate the work that you've done to solve the problem yourself and any errors you're seeing, before asking for help.  This will help people identify exactly what it is you're having trouble with and help you lern.

Comment: Where is the problem? Your analysis for list.get(0).get(0) is also correct

Answer (score 2):

Here is how great JavaScript and JSON work together when it comes to serializing data structures and objects.

All this available right in the JavaScript console of modern browsers:

```
JSON.stringify([["-1.816513","52.5487566"],["-1.8164913","52.548824"]])
"[["-1.816513","52.5487566"],["-1.8164913","52.548824"]]"
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([["-1.816513","52.5487566"],["-1.8164913","52.548824"]]))
[
Array[2]
0: "-1.816513"
1: "52.5487566"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
, 
Array[2]
0: "-1.8164913"
1: "52.548824"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: please see OP's language it is Java not JS.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
.toString()
```

this can help you..
[Convert array of strings into a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283444/convert-array-of-strings-into-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to read documentation about [Split method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and  [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

And to transform array to List use `Arrays.asList` :

```
   Integer[] spam = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 };
   Arrays.asList(spam);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the

`string('[["-1.816513","52.5487566"],["-1.8164913","52.548824"]]')`

as  the result `JSONObject.toSting()`.

So you can find the way to convert string to `JSONObject` just like that:

```
String json="{[[\"-1.816513\",\"52.5487566\"],[\"-1.8164913\",\"52.548824\"]]}";
JSONObject jsonObj = JSONObject.fromObject(json);
```

And you need import `json-lib.jar` and any other jars relied on.