# How to convert string array to string

Tags: java, arrays

I have made a method which random the string array and print it out.
But now I need to use that method and assign it to a string to count the number of letters in the string.
I cant seem to find the answer anywhere.
Is there any way that I can do? Help me out. I m a beginner in programming.

Comment: please see the link you will get the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283444/convert-array-of-strings-into-a-string-in-java

Comment: please post your code I can give you answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arrays.toString() in combination with StringBuilder/StringBuffer to iterate over the array and keep on appending the array element to this string object .

EX:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   for(String string : array) {
   stringBuilder.append(string);
 }
 return stringBuilder.toString();
```

For counting the no. of letters you can use:

```
String input = userInput.toLowerCase();// Make your input lower case.
int[] alphabetArray = new int[26];
for ( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++ ) {
     char ch=  input.charAt(i);
     int value = (int) ch;
     if (value >= 97 && value <= 122){
     alphabetArray[ch-'a']++;
    }
}
```

And for displaying the result:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < alphabetArray.length; i++) {
  if(alphabetArray[i]>0){
    char ch = (char) (i+97);
    System.out.println(ch +"  : "+alphabetArray[i]);   //Show the result.
  }         
 }
```