# Using toString() with Arrays Java -New programmer

Tags: java

My goal is to print out all the words in the array and make sure they are in a string.( In order).
So far I'm at:

```
public class Freddy {
    private String[] words = new String[]{"Hello", "name", "is", "Bob"};


    public String toString() {
        for (int i = 0; i <words.length; i++)
            System.out.println(words[i]);

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println();//Not sure not to print out here. When I say print(words) it gives error "Error:(16, 24) java: non-static variable words cannot be referenced from a static context"
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your `toString()` method you have should return type of `void` if you plan on returning nothing (mind you, that wouldn't be the usual approach to implementing `toSting()`).  Instead you should actually return a `String`.

Comment: So instead of System.out.println(words[i]); I should do return(words[i]);

Comment: You can use the `StringBuilder` class. The first line of the method can be `StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();` So instead of `System.out.println(words[i]);` you would put `stringBuilder.append(words[i]);` Then you would `return stringBuilder.toString();`

Comment: I believe this has been answered before please see this link: [Click Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283444/convert-array-of-strings-into-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You error is because you are trying to access to instance variable in static method(main) without creating the instance.

To fix your error:

1. make your array static:

   `private static String[] words = ...//make it static`

**or**

2. create an instance before you get access to it:

   `System.out.println(new Freddy());//This will call it's`toString()`method.`

**In order to convert an array to String**,  use [Arrays#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[]))  is a better way:

```
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.toString(words);//Convert the array into string, toString returns null is a bad habbit.
}
```

Check [How to convert an int array to String with toString method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904911/java-how-to-convert-int-array-to-string-with-tostring-method) for more details

Comment: @EmanOdame 
 
I think you have to do it by yourself, if your string is easy, you may simplily use :"Arrays.toString(words).replace(","," ")".replace("{|}","")

Comment: @EmanOdame, try this: `Arrays.toString(words).replaceAll(","," ")".replaceAll("{|}","").replaceAll("^\\[|\\]$", "");`

Answer (score 1):

A `static` method can only use `static` fields from class. 
Your `main()` method is `static`, then your method `toString()` and array `String[] words` must be `static` too.

However, in your case, you should follow the way that @Arvind show.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is main() is static, whereas words is an instance variable, meaning it cannot exist without the instance of Freddy.

Simply pass the instance of class:

```
System.out.println(new Freddy());
```