# Array of Strings to String without using for loop

Tags: java

How to convert `String[]` to `String` in `Java` without using for loop ?

I know how to convert using for loop but I want to  convert it without using any loop (`for` or `while`).

Comment: Already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283444/convert-array-of-strings-into-a-string-in-java

Comment: A little Google is always helpful.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a loop? Loops are a fundamental part of Java. Your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt i guess is some kind of educational excercise or homework...

Answer (score 3):

Use [Arrays.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])) to convert it.

> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array. If the array contains other arrays as elements, they are converted to strings by the Object.toString() method inherited from Object, which describes their identities rather than their contents.

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays.toString()**

**Example**

```
String[] arr = new String[2];
arr[0] = "Str 1"; arr[1] = "Str 2";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```