# Alternative for String.join in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to concatenate an ArrayList with commas as separators. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-opposite-of-sp), stating it's possible to use `String.join` in Java.

When I try to use this however, Android Studio gives the following error:

> Cannot resolve method 'join(java.lang.String, java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'

Is there a good, concise alternative for Android Studio (instead of using a for loop)?

Comment: TextUtils.join() maybe?

Comment: try StringUtils.join

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can use `TextUtils.join` instead:

```
String result = TextUtils.join(", ", list);
```

(`String.join` was added in Java 8, which is why you can't use it in Android.)

Comment: To save a few clicks to non Android Studio users: `import android.text.TextUtils`

Comment: Using TextUtils may cause problem with unit test. In that case use a function from here : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/TextUtils.java

Comment: @Subin: What kind of problem? And why link to TextUtils as an alternative to TextUtils? I'm afraid your comment isn't really clear.

Comment: @JonSkeet Cause this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/q/35763289/1372424 Solution from here : https://medium.com/@okmanideep/dont-create-that-stringutils-to-unit-test-your-android-class-8ab32af34e84

Comment: @Subin: Right, so *specifically* if you're using Mockito. And note that the solution is a matter of copying the TextUtils source into your test project.

Answer (score 8):

```
String[] List ={"<html>","<body>","<title>"};
String abc;       
abc =TextUtils.join("\n", List);
textmsg.getText().insert(textmsg.getSelectionStart(), abc);
```

**result:**

> ```
> <html>
> <body>
> <title>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
TextUtils.join(", ", your_list);
```