# Need help to write a unit test using Mockito and JUnit4

Tags: android, mockito, junit4

Need help to write a unit test for the below code using Mockito and JUnit4,

```
public class MyFragmentPresenterImpl { 
      public Boolean isValid(String value) {
        return !(TextUtils.isEmpty(value));
      }
}
```

I tried below method:
MyFragmentPresenter mMyFragmentPresenter

```
@Before
public void setup(){
    mMyFragmentPresenter=new MyFragmentPresenterImpl();
}

@Test
public void testEmptyValue() throws Exception {
    String value=null;
    assertFalse(mMyFragmentPresenter.isValid(value));
}
```

but it returns following exception,

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Method isEmpty in android.text.TextUtils
>   not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details. at
>   android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty(TextUtils.java) at ....

Answer (score 41):

Because of JUnit TestCase class cannot use Android related APIs, we have to Mock it.
Use `PowerMockito` to Mock the static class.

Add two lines above your test case class,

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TextUtils.class)
public class YourTest
{

}
```

And the setup code

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(TextUtils.class);
    PowerMockito.when(TextUtils.isEmpty(any(CharSequence.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            CharSequence a = (CharSequence) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            return !(a != null && a.length() > 0);
        }
    });
}
```

That implement `TextUtils.isEmpty()` with our own logic.

Also, add dependencies in `app.gradle` files.

```
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.2"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.2"
```

Thanks `Behelit`'s and `Exception`'s answer.

Comment: This works only partly. I had that this does not work when calling TextUtils.isEmpty(null) since that didnt match the when statement. See my answer for a better solution

Answer (score 9):

Use PowerMockito

Add this above your class name, and include any other CUT class names (classes under test)

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({TextUtils.class})
public class ContactUtilsTest
{
```

Add this to your @Before

```
@Before
public void setup(){
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(TextUtils.class);
    mMyFragmentPresenter=new MyFragmentPresenterImpl();
}
```

This will make PowerMockito return default values for methods within TextUtils

You would also have to add the relevant gradle depedencies

```
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.2"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.2"
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a known issue as mentioned by @Exception. In my case, I also stumbled upon same situation but on advice of senior dev decided to use `Strings.isNullOrEmpty()` instead of `TextUtils.isEmpty()`. It turned out to be a nice way to avoid it.

Update: I should better mention it that this utility function [`Strings.isNullOrEmpty()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html) requires Guava library.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue, due to a clause in Testing Fundamental of Android which says:

> You can use the JUnit TestCase class to do unit testing on a class
>   that does not call Android APIs.

The default behavior is problematic when using classes like `Log` or `TextUtils`.

To sum up:

1. `android.jar` is mock before, so some Android API return value may not be as expected.
2. JUnit itself is a single measure for the java code, so try not to use the Android API methods.

**Source:** http://www.liangfeizc.com/2016/01/28/unit-test-on-android/

Answer (score 4):

add this line in your gradle file in case of Android Studio.

```
android{
....
 testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
 }
}
```

Comment: Having the default value be true. Will result in textUtils always returning true. But there might be cases where you what to test a false case. Test coverage that checks branching will miss the case that is false.

Answer (score 4):

You should use Robolectric:

```
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.4.2"
```

And then

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class TestClass {
    ...
}
```

Comment: While this is mostly true, its not necessarily that you **should** use Robolectric, its merely a **could**, since not all apps can use Robolectric (for example when you use SQLCipher)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this error by running the test class with the following.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class MySimpleTest {
.....a bunch of test cases
}
```

This wiki page explains in greater detail
https://github.com/yahoo/squidb/wiki/Unit-testing-with-model-objects

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**

I would like to provide a Kotlin and a Java version.

Kotlin version:

```
import android.text.TextUtils

import org.junit.Before

import org.junit.runner.RunWith

import org.mockito.Matchers.any

import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito
```

import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest

```
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner



@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)

@PrepareForTest(TextUtils::class)

class UserOwnedDataTest1 {



    @Before

    fun setup() {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(TextUtils::class.java)

        PowerMockito.`when`(TextUtils.isEmpty(any(CharSequence::class.java))).thenAnswer { invocation ->

            val a = invocation.arguments[0] as? CharSequence

           a?.isEmpty() ?: true

        }

    }

}
```

Java version:

```
import android.text.TextUtils;



import org.junit.Before;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;

import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;

import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;



import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;



@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

@PrepareForTest(TextUtils.class)

public final class UserOwnedDataTest2 {



    @Before

    public void setup() {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(TextUtils.class);

        PowerMockito.when(TextUtils.isEmpty(any(CharSequence.class))).thenAnswer((Answer<Boolean>) invocation -> {

            CharSequence a = (CharSequence) invocation.getArguments()[0];

            return !(a != null && a.length() > 0);

        });

    }

}
```

Do not forget to add the dependencies:

```
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2"

testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.2"

testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2"

testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.2"
```

I remember that we still need another dependency, but not clearly.

Anyway you could fix the missing dependency easily.

**Solution 2:**

Or you could add the same package and class name with TextUtils

```
package android.text;



public class TextUtils {

    public static boolean isEmpty( CharSequence str) {

        return str == null || str.length() == 0;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I replaces everywhere in my project `TextUtils.isEmpty(...)` with this:

```
/**
 * Util class to be used instead of Android classes for Junit tests.
 */
public class Utils {

    /**
     * Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.
     * @param str the string to be examined
     * @return true if str is null or zero length
     */
    public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable CharSequence str) {
        return str == null || str.length() == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a followup to Johnny's answer, to catch TextUtils.isEmpty(null) calls as well, you could use this piece of code.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(TextUtils.class);
PowerMockito.when(TextUtils.isEmpty(any()))
    .thenAnswer((Answer<Boolean>) invocation -> {
        Object s = invocation.getArguments()[0];
        return s == null || s.length() == 0;
    });
```

Comment: The above helps but to be absolutely correct you need do and a extra check like (CharSequence)s).length 
or in kotlin
 s == null || (s is CharSequence && s.length == 0)

Comment: I took your idea and completed it like-
`PowerMockito.`when`(TextUtils.isEmpty(any())).thenAnswer { invocation ->
            val str = invocation.arguments[0]
            return@thenAnswer str == null || (str is String && str.length == 0)
        }`

Answer (score 0):

With newer power mock (2.0.9) and mockito (3.9.0) I had. to change execution to this one:

```java
when(TextUtils.isEmpty(any())).thenAnswer((Answer<Boolean>) invocation -> {
    CharSequence a = (CharSequence) invocation.getArguments()[0];
    return a == null || a.length() == 0;
});
```