# TextUtils.join returns NULL on Unit Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, textutils

I'm joining a list of strings by using TextUtils.join but it's returning NULL. I'm doing this on a simple unit test.

Here's the code in question:

```
@Test
public void testJoinText(){
    List<String> letters = Lists.newArrayList();
    letters.add("A");
    letters.add("B");
    letters.add("C");
    letters.add("D");
    letters.add("E");

    String joinedLetters = TextUtils.join(";", letters); //This is returning null.
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763289/need-help-to-write-a-unit-test-using-mockito-and-junit4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextUtils` class is in `android.util.*`. So you cannot use TextUtils' functions in test package. You should test this code in androidTest package.