# Split Strings based on white spaces

Tags: java, android, regex, textutils

(The title may be misleading. I always though the hard part is finding the proper title :D)

Well, sentences are just (long) strings. I want to display these sentences but in a reversed way. Example: `"StackOverflow is a community of awesome programmers"` would become `"programmers awesome of community a is StackOverflow"`.

So my idea is to have a delimiter, here a ***blank space***. Whenever texts are entered and the space bar pressed, save that word in a list, an ArrayList and then just display them in inverted order in a textView.

So far i can only output texts but without blank spaces (`programmersawesomeofcommunityaisStackOverflow`) and only using a button. I use the below code to do that:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String[] sentence = input.getText().toString().split(" "); //This split() method is the culprit!
            ArrayList<String> wordArray = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String word : sentence) {
                    wordArray.add(word);
            }
            Collections.sort(wordArray);
            StringBuilder invertedSentence = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = wordArray.size(); i > 0; i--) {
                invertedSentence.append(wordArray.get(i - 1));
            }
            output.setText(invertedSentence.toString());
        }
    });
```

How can I have a sentence be saved (automatically) in a list as split words when the system detect a white space? And add blank spaces in the output sentences?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why are you sorting `wordArray`? And the *regex* for whitespace is `\\s`.

Comment: `""` is an _empty string. It doesn't even contain whitespace. I'd assume you either mean `" "` or `"\\s+"` (any whitespace including tabs etc.). Also you might want to add some spaces when assembling the inverted sentence, e.g. via `invertedSentence.append(" ").append(wordArray.get(i - 1));` or yet better use Java 8's streams to invert the array and concatenate the strings using `join(" ")`.

Comment: And on a side note: `Collections.sort(wordArray);` would _not_ invert the list but sort it, i.e. your example text would then become `a awesome community is of programmers StackOverflow` (assuming the rest is correct).

Comment: @Thomas Thank you. I was trying to find a way to add spaces to the inverted sentence

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So that I can loop backwards to output the inverted sentence. I was wrong

Comment: Yes you're right, @Thomas the output is not inverted

Comment: To reverse the array you could try `Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.reverseOrder())` or for your list just use `Collections.reverseOrder(wordArray)` (and then `wordArray.stream().join(" ")`).

Comment: `Collections.reverseOrder(String)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the comments have good suggestions, but here is one approach you could use:

```
    String[] sentence = new String("StackOverflow is a community of awesome programmers").split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> wordArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String word : sentence) {
       wordArray.add(0, word);
    }

    String backwards = String.join(" ", wordArray);
    System.out.println(backwards);
```

Output

```
programmers awesome of community a is StackOverflow
```

Comment: `String.join` requires Android O

Comment: @esQmo_, the code you posted appears to split on an empty string.

Comment: That's a typo as i didn't copy paste it. I'm going to fix that

Comment: How to make this code work on android devices version < O ?

Comment: This answer, might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802971/alternative-for-string-join-in-android

It suggests using `TextUtils.join`

Comment: Thanks so much. However, this solves only one part of my questions. How to make it detect automatically as user is typing?

Comment: Solved that part too using TextWatcher