# Spark java DataFrame Date filter based on max Date another DataFrame

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes

1. Max of date column from one dataframe :: **one column, one row - df1, column : maxdate**
2. Multiple records having date column :: **df2 columns : col1,col2,col3..colDate**

I want filter df2 based df1.maxdate, `df2.colDate > df1.maxdate`

If I specify like below then its working.

```
df2.filter(col("colDate").gt(lit(2020-01-01)))
```

However, I'm not able to use df1.maxdate.
I'm trying java to achieve this soulution.

DataType is date in both dataFrame columns

I m trying to achieve this through spark transformation

```
select * from a 
where a.col > (select max(b.col) from b)
```

In my example

```
Table a = df2
Table b = df1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`createTempView`** on `two dataframes` then using **sql query** we can filter the only required date.

**`Example:`**

**`Option1: using createTempView:`**

```
df1.show()
//+----------+
//|   Maxdate|
//+----------+
//|2020-01-01|
//+----------+

df2.show()
//+----------+----+----+
//|   colDate|col1|col2|
//+----------+----+----+
//|2020-01-01|   A|   B|
//|2020-01-03|   C|   D|
//+----------+----+----+


df1.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")

df2.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp1")

sql("select * from tmp1 where coldate > (select maxdate from tmp)").show()
//+----------+----+----+
//|   colDate|col1|col2|
//+----------+----+----+
//|2020-01-03|   C|   D|
//+----------+----+----+
```

**`Option-2:Using dataframe variable:`**

Another way would be **storing into variable** then using the variable then use the variable in dataframe **`filter`**.

```
val max_val=df1.collect()(0)(0).toString

df2.filter(col("colDate") > max_val).show()
//+----------+----+----+
//|   colDate|col1|col2|
//+----------+----+----+
//|2020-01-03|   C|   D|
//+----------+----+----+
```

**`Option-3:Using dataframe crossJoin and expr:`**

In this case we are not creating variable instead using dataframe column to filter only the required rows.

```
df2.crossJoin(df1).
filter(expr("colDate > Maxdate")).
drop("Maxdate").
show()
//+----------+----+----+
//|   colDate|col1|col2|
//+----------+----+----+
//|2020-01-03|   C|   D|
//+----------+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks, I want try out option 2: `val max_val=df1.collect()(0)(0).toString`. However, I tried to google df.collect for java to convert into java syntax but no luck :( Any idea from where I can get java syntax for this, any spark documentation page will be helpful

Comment: java also has `.collect()` but not `.toString` so use `.collect()` returns array of strings then convert them to string using `Arrays.toString(arr)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283444/convert-array-of-strings-into-a-string-in-java

Comment: I have tried below code `df2.select("maxdate").collect().toString()` in java.. where my df2 is having 1 column(maxdate) and 1 row. kind of stuck here now. if I write `df.collect() [0][0]` its not working. Also if write `df.collect()` then return datatype is Row..

Comment: I used collectAsList option then extracted from list value. thanks

Answer (score 1):

the below code might be helpful for you,

```
val df1 = Seq(('2020-01-02')).toDF("Maxate")

df1.show()

/*
+----------+
|    Maxate|
+----------+
|2020-01-02|
+----------+
*/

val df2 = Seq(("2020-01-01","A","B"),("2020-01-03","C","D")).toDF("colDate","col1","col2")

/*
+----------+----+----+
|   colDate|col1|col2|
+----------+----+----+
|2020-01-01|   A|   B|
|2020-01-03|   C|   D|
+----------+----+----+
*/
val maxDate=df1.collect.map(row=>row.getString(0)).mkString

df2.filter($"colDate">maxDate).show()

/*
+----------+----+----+
|   colDate|col1|col2|
+----------+----+----+
|2020-01-03|   C|   D|
+----------+----+----+
*/
```

Comment: your answer helped me but 484 provide 3 options hence marked that as my answer. I dont have credit to upvote your answer now, will do that soon