# How to query the most duplicate data column in SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm having a problem querying a SQLite database in Android. The way I do it now is only `ORDER BY`, but it doesn't work, only the sorting function.

```
Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Userdetails ORDER BY ID DESC", null);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD6IK.png)

How to query all the most similar values ​​in the `ID` column? In this case `1ABC` occurs at most so it should appear twenty-two times.

Comment: Please add your data to the question, so it's easier for us to test against. You might want to check out the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pages.

Comment: Edit your question and explain better what you want with sample data and expected results as tect and not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about ties in the number of duplicates then use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Userdetails 
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM Userdetails GROUP BY ID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You should group by ID and count each items:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count FROM Userdetails GROUP BY ID
```

2- Then give it a name and use its result for sorting:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count FROM Userdetails GROUP BY ID ) innerQuery 
ORDER BY innerQuery.count DESC
```

and in your code sample:

```
Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count FROM Userdetails GROUP BY ID ) innerQuery ORDER BY innerQuery.count DESC", null);
```

Comment: I do it your way but the result i get `ID` column returns two results `1ABC` `2ABC`. My question is how to query all the most similar values ​​in the `ID` column, in which case `1ABC` occurs the most should be queried.

Answer (score 0):

Please be clearer with your question and what you wanna do. Also, this isn't really a java related question. However I rewrote a solution I **found online**, hope this helps

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    yourDatabase
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) DESC;
```

Comment: the `OVER` clause I don't see a line of SQLite talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you really don't need all columns for this, so don't use "*". Also, that would likely disrupt the `COUNT` and `DISTINCT` for your needs.

So instead of `ORDER BY`, use `GROUP BY` to get the info you need. You still need `ORDER BY` to get the list in order and add in `LIMIT` to get the largest amount of duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, COUNT(PROFILE) AS COUNT FROM USERDETAILS
GROUP BY ID  
ORDER BY COUNT desc  
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: sorry, when I use your query, Android Studio gives an error.

Comment: @SaHiRo, what error does it give?

Comment: Oh sorry, just mistyped my column name. But I ran it again and your files didn't return any data. I think `ORDER BY` is already filtered.

Comment: @SaHiRo, even if it was already filtered, it should still give results. I accidentally had the wrong table name in the query, so I've updated that, if that was the cause of the first error.

Comment: Logcat in Android Studio does not log any results. `ArrayList<String> listProfile = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> listID = new ArrayList<String>(); if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                listProfile.add(cursor.getString(0));
                listID.add(cursor.getString(1)); }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "KQ ------ Profile:" + listProfile);
        Log.i(TAG, "KQ ------ ID:" + listID);`

Comment: @SaHiRo, if you try it without the `LIMIT 1`, does it still not return any results?

Comment: @SaHiRo, you need to convert your array of strings to a single string before pushing it to a log, or you won't actually see what's in the array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283444/convert-array-of-strings-into-a-string-in-java/5283753