# What changes do I make to my code to allow more than one word to be translated to Pig Latin and printed?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I made a Java Script that took word input and turned it into a Pig Latin version of said word:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  static Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

  static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    return (c == 'A' || c == 'a' || c == 'E' || c == 'e' || c == 'I' || c == 'i' || c == 'O' || c == 'o' || c == 'U'
        || c == 'u');
  }

  static String pigLatin(String oldWord) {
    System.out.println("\r\n");
    System.out.println("What word should I translate?");
    oldWord = myObj.nextLine();
    System.out.println("");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(800);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.print(".");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.print(".");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.print(".");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.print("\r\n");
    System.out.print("\r\n");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    int len = oldWord.length();
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (isVowel(oldWord.charAt(i))) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (index == -1)
      return "-1";

    return oldWord.substring(index) + oldWord.substring(0, index) + "ay";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String newWord = pigLatin("graphic");
    if (newWord == "-1")
      System.out.print("No vowels found. Pig Latin not possible");
    else {
      System.out.print("Your word in Pig Latin is: \033[1m" + newWord + "\033[0m");
    }
  }
}
```

This takes whatever is typed, moves all characters before the first vowel to the end, and then adds "ay" to it. I am now trying to change this to make it translate a sentence instead, so I decided to try using a string array for this, but I probably did something stupid or missed something important because I ended up with this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  static Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

  static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    return (c == 'A' || c == 'a' || c == 'E' || c == 'e' || c == 'I' || c == 'i' || c == 'O' || c == 'o' || c == 'U'
        || c == 'u');
  }

  static String pigLatin(String sentance) {
    System.out.println("\r\n");
    System.out.println("What sentance should I translate?");
    String oldWord = myObj.nextLine();
    System.out.println("");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(800);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.print(".");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.print(".");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.print(".");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.print("\r\n");
    System.out.print("\r\n");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    
    String[] words = oldWord.split(" ");
    for (String word : words) {
      int len = word.length();
      int index = -1;
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (isVowel(word.charAt(i))) {
          index = i;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (index == -1)
        return "-1";
      return word.substring(index) + word.substring(0, index) + "ay";
    }
    return words.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String newWord = pigLatin("graphic");
    System.out.print("Your sentance in Pig Latin is: \033[1m" + newWord + "\033[0m");
  }
}
```

Which just made it only translate the first word and delete the rest. I'm still new to Java, and I have no idea how to fix this problem.

Comment: You have to take a look to these lines: ```return "-1";```, ```return word.substring(index) + word.substring(0, index) + "ay";```. Return within a for-loop does not mean it will continue with the loop, but your function is finished immediately and with that value returned.

Comment: @Enowneb Thank you, as I didn't know this about loops, but is there a way to get around this? Or maybe a way to replace using returns inside of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the code will just return the first word and stop processing the remaining lies here:

```java
String[] words = oldWord.split(" ");
for (String word : words) {
    int len = word.length();
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (isVowel(word.charAt(i))) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index == -1)
        return "-1"; // Stop processing anymore
    return word.substring(index) + word.substring(0, index) + "ay"; // Stop processing anymore
}
```

The above is the for-loop that processes all the separate words from your sentence. However, a `return` statement will stop proceeding your `pigLatin()` function further and directly returns that value. So if you want to process all words from the sentence, you must not call `return` within the for-loop.

So what you can do, is to create another variable to hold your processed words. Like:

```java
String[] words = oldWord.split(" ");
// Create another String array to hold your processed words
String[] pigLatinWords = new String[words.length];
int wordCounter = 0;
for (String word : words) {
    int len = word.length();
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (isVowel(word.charAt(i))) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index == -1) {
        // Store the processed word in this new Array
        pigLatinWords[wordCounter++] = word;
        // Continue with the for-loop without processing the code below
        continue;
    }
    // Store the processed word in this new Array
    pigLatinWords[wordCounter++] = word.substring(index) + word.substring(0, index) + "ay";
}
```

And at the end you should call return like:

```java
return String.join(" ", pigLatinWords);
```

Or you should refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283444/convert-array-of-strings-into-a-string-in-java) to implement your own concatenation function if you are using *Java 7 or below*.

Changing the above code should produce a result matching with your expectation:

> What sentance should I translate?
> graphic graphic
>
> ...
>
> Your sentance in Pig Latin is: aphicgray aphicgray

And note that you should not call `toString()` on `String[]`, or you will end up having something like the hexadecimal hashcode of `String[]` printed:

> Your sentance in Pig Latin is: [Ljava.lang.String;@7a79be86