# How can I convert a String to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to convert a String to an array with objects (one object for each char of the string).

I have this code:

```
public void inputPin(String pin)
    {
        char[] charArray = pin.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0;i < charArray.length;i++)
        {

        }

    }
```

I need to place inside the for loop a method like pressButton() and this method will receive as a parameter a String (that is one of the characters of the pin).

How can I get each of the characters of the array and use it as a parameter of the pressButton() method?

Comment: No ideas. The question is not clear. Not the least bit...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413586/string-to-string-array-conversion-in-java

Comment: Why not just get the size of the string and then create an array of objects based on that size?

Comment: So...you're looking to a solution to cram into the `for` loop?

Comment: Yes, I need a solution to cram into the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
String pin = "Sample";
char[] charArray = pin.toCharArray();
for(char c : charArray)
{
    pressButton(""+c); // to convert char to String
}
```

Comment: It's issue with other point, just try to print all characters, give your detail code so it can be identify.

Comment: I had a method calling to itself, that was the error. Finally your code worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get array of symbols using split

```
pin.split("");
```

split will return array of String objects - you can convert it to char if you want

Answer (score 1):

To convert a char into a String, use

```
String.valueOf([your char here])
```

You can also do it by using concatenation so

```
[yourchar] + ""
```

will return a String, too.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this to get an array of `Character object` from resulting char array:

```
char[] charArray = pin.toCharArray();
Character[] objArray = new Character[charArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    objArray[i] = new Character(charArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    char[] charArray = pin.toCharArray();
    Character[] characterArray = new Character[charArray.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        characterArray[i] = charArray[i];
    }
```