# String variable to Array in java

Tags: java, php, openlayers

```
map.addLayer(
    new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(layer_id,{
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: 'ajax.jsp?action=getPoi',
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.Text()
        }),

    projection: map.displayProjection,) 
    displayInLayerSwitcher:false
    });
```

**in the above code i get a request variable such as**

```
bbox=-0.12856930694582,51.499827348159,-0.1114031692505,51.510512307879
```

and i need to put the value in bbox to an array in java how is it possible
i saw an example in php such as

```
$bbox_vars = explode(",", $bbox);
```

Comment: The code that you've posted does not look like [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), but rather [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). Can you clarify what you mean when you say you "get a request variable"?

Comment: Yes. The above code doesn't look like java code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [string to string array conversion in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413586/string-to-string-array-conversion-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use split in java

```
String[] bboxvar=bbox.split(",");
```

Comment: @oops, sorry, comment removed.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran it's ok

Comment: @NambiNarayanan Thanks sir 

but still i have a doubt how to assign that value into double variable given below is which i wrote which is correct ?? 
minlon,minlat all are double variable

minlon = bboxvar(0);
minlat = bboxvar.getDouble(1);
maxlon = bboxvar.getDouble(2);
maxlat = bboxvar.getDouble(3);

Comment: @AnasA It's Ok Glad to help