# How to compare a string to a specific compartment of an array of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, string, compare

I'm making a quiz like game. I have two arrays (One with the states and the other with the capitals). Basically it asks the user what capital goes with a random state. I want that if the user inputs the correct state for it to be like nice job or whatever but I do not know how to compare the user input to the specific array compartment. I tried .contains but no avail...
Any help?

My bad - I'm using Java

For Example

```
if(guess.equals(capitals[random]))
```

where guess is the string and capitals is the array and random is the random number

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413586/string-to-string-array-conversion-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic similar to this should work. You want to save the user input to a String variable, and then compare it to an n sized array.

```
for(int i=0; i<arrayName.length();i++)
{
     if(userinputString.equalsIgnorCase(arrayName[i])
     {
          System.out.println("HUrray!");
     }//end if

}//end for
```

Ok so you are somehow producing a random number, and then need to compare the input to the String in the capital Array for that random number/

Im assuming the arrays are ordered such that capitals[10] gives you the capital for states[10].

If so, just save the index to a variable.

```
int ranNum=RandomNumFunction();
```

Then just see if

```
if(capitals[ranNum].equalsIgnoreCase(userInput))
//do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want a mapping `String -> String (State -> Capital)`. This could be done using a `Map<String, String>` or by creating a `State` class which will contains its name and its capital as attributes.

But to my mind, the best option is to use an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) as you know that there is 50 states. Here's a small example.

```
public class Test {  

    static final State[] states = State.values();
    static Random r = new Random();
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args){
        State random = states[r.nextInt(states.length)];
        random.askQuestion();
        String answer = sc.nextLine();
        if(answer.equals(random.getCapital())){
            System.out.println("Congrats");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not really");
        }       
    }   
}

enum State {
    //Some states, add the other ones
    ALABAMA("Montgomery"),
    ALASKA("Juneau");

    private final String capital;

    private State(String capital){
        this.capital = capital;
    }

    public String getCapital(){
        return this.capital;
    }

    public void askQuestion(){
        System.out.println("What capital goes with "+this.name()+"?");
    }
}
```