# how to print first Characters from multiple string in java?

Tags: java, string

i want to print first character from multiple word , this word coming from api , like 
DisplayName: arwa othman . 
i want to print the letter (a) and (o).
can anyone to help me please ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
   public String getFirstWords(String original){
       String firstWord= "";
       String[] split = original.split(" ");

       for(String value : split){
            firstWord+= value.substring(0,1);
        }

        return firstWord;
    }
```

And use this as

```
String Result = getFirstWords("arwa othman");
```

**Edit**
Using `Regex`

```
String name = "arwa othman";
String firstWord= "";
for(String s : name.split("\\s+")){
 firstWord += s.charAt(0);
}

String Result = firstWord;
```

Comment: @Mohammad altaani Is your problem solved?

Comment: @Mohammadaltaani  Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted,so it may help others also.

Comment: how can i make accepted ??

Comment: @Mohammadaltaani To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.And to upvote click upper arrow.

Comment: ok i will , can u help me to split string from array ??

Comment: @Mohammadaltaani Did you mean to convert string to array?

Comment: yes i marked , and yes i want to convert string to array ...

Comment: @Mohammadaltaani this posy may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413586/string-to-string-array-conversion-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the Apache Commons Langs library and use the initials() method , you can get more information from here [http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#initials(java.lang.String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#initials%28java.lang.String%29)

I am quoting a sample code snippet that might be useful :

```
WordUtils.initials(null)             = null
WordUtils.initials("")               = ""
WordUtils.initials("Ben John Lee")   = "BJL"
WordUtils.initials("Ben J.Lee")      = "BJ"
```

Comment: If you like the answer you can vote up (a stack overflow style for expressing gratitude) :)

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
String[] splitArray = displayName.split("\\s+");
char[] initials = new char[splitArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
    initials[i] = splitArray[i].charAt(0);
}
```

This will give you a char array. If you want a String array use String.valueOf(char)