# convert String to String array

Tags: java

i try to create a program to encrypt text into code with my own rule. but, i found some problems to split the text and send it to array

i want to see this in Msg array

```
Msg[0] = "h";
Msg[1] = "e";
Msg[2] = "l";
Msg[3] = "l";
Msg[4] = "o";
```

and i try to code like this

```
String text = "hello";
String[] Msg = new String[] {text};
```

this code works, but the result isn't like i want. can you help me to solve this problem

thanks..

Comment: How is it not working? What you're showing it's doing at the top appears to be what I would expect it to do. What is the result that you would like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [string to string array conversion in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413586/string-to-string-array-conversion-in-java)

Comment: Do you want to get array of characters? If so you can get `char []` via `yourString.toCharArray()`. Or do you really want to get array of Strings with each character separated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to split the string up into each character then use this code:

```
String text = "hello";
String[] Msg = text.split("(?!^)");
```

This uses a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to split the code by every spot that is between two characters (excluding the first blank spot).

Here's how it works:

`.split("");` would be fine for splitting the string if you're using java 8 as @Pshemo pointed out. But below that you will end up with an array that starts with "" as the first element.

This regular expression avoids that because it uses a *negative lookahead* `(?!)` to make sure to not match the beginning of a line, which is represented by the `^` character.

Comment: Any explanation of `(!?^)`? BTW [this regex is no longer needed since Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718744/why-does-split-in-java-8-sometimes-removes-empty-strings-if-they-are-at-start-of), you can just use `split("")`.

Comment: please explain why this would be preferable to simply `toCharArray()`?

Comment: @drewmoore Different return types, this actually does **exactly** what OP *described* in example (it returns `String[]`, not `char[]`).

Comment: @drewmoore Because the OP requests that the array be of `String`.

Comment: indeed he does. i'm sorry, i misread the question..

Answer (score 4):

char[] String.toCharArray() is probably what you are looking for.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()

Comment: The desired output indicates that `Msg` is a `string[]` and not a `char[]`. Why would someone do that, I don't know, but I'm afraid this does not answer the question.

Comment: Sometimes the asker doesn't really know what they want.  Hence the "is probably what you are looking for".  @BitNinja's answer above is the solution if the OP's question was exactly what he was asking for.