# How to transform a string to an array

Tags: javascript

How to transform a string of this format `'[11, 66]'` to an array ?

`Array.isArray('[11, 66]')` return false since it's considered as string?

Comment: And would the expected result be  an array with just the two values `11` and `66` (hint: it is valid JSON) ?

Comment: Alternatively, `'[1, 2]'.substring(1, s.length - 1).split(', ').map(str => +str)` also works, but is less robust than `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Please refer to the following link, it can be very useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413586/string-to-string-array-conversion-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to do this would be [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

> The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string.

In your example:

```
JSON.parse('[11, 66]')
```

Output:

```
[11, 66]
```

Answer (score 2):

If the string is a valid JSON string, then use `JSON.parse`:

```
var array = JSON.parse(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use JSON API ?

```
JSON.parse(string); // turn a JSON string into a plain object (or an array as your example)
JSON.stringify(object); // turn an object (or an array) into JSON string
```

Also work for arrays!